# CRON Expression to trigger Azure Function on the last day of each month

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cron, azure-functions

Is there any CRON expression i can use to trigger an Azure Function on the last day of each month? It seems like such a typical scenario for a timer trigger, i'm suprised that i'm struggling to figure this out.

I'm currently using a workaround by triggering on dates 28-31 of each month and checking in code if it's the last day of the month, but that solution feels a bit hacky.

Even a definitive "Not possible" would be appreciated.

**EDIT**:
Here is the code

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;

namespace MyProsj.Functions.Triggers
{
    public static class LastOfEachMonth
    {
        [FunctionName("LastOfEachMonth")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 20 28-31 * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Day == 1)
            {
                //DO STUFF HERE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the "L" doesnt work in Azure CRON expressions the solution we use is to check the last day of the month. So trigger on days 28-31 but then inspect the day to see if it's the last day of the month. C# has DaysInMonth property on the DateTime. Use that to create the DateTime representing the last dau of the month and then if its Saturday take off 1 day. If Sunday take off 2 days.

```
      var daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Month);

        var lastDayOfMonth = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Month, daysInMonth);   
     
        var lastWorkingDayOfMonth = lastDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek switch
        {
            DayOfWeek.Saturday => lastDayOfMonth.AddDays(-1),
            DayOfWeek.Sunday => lastDayOfMonth.AddDays(-2),
            _ => lastDayOfMonth,
        };
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -1):

Here is the Corn Expression for to run the trigger of the Azure Function on the last day of every Month. at 10:15 AM

```
15 10 * * 5L
```

[image]

For Further information check this [Corn Expressions](https://www.easycron.com/faq/What-cron-expression-does-easycron-support).

Comment: 'L' doesnt seem to work in Azure Functions..
"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions: The schedule expression '0 0 20 L * *' was not recognized as a valid cron expression or timespan string."

Comment: Looks like you want to trigger your function at last day  8PM every month as per that you need to use the below corn expression 0 20 L * * for further information check http://www.brightxpress.com/user/appendix/cron_expressions.htm